# Trouble importing my model materials to unity

Tags: texturing, materials, import

I need some help with my models and why i can't see the materials in unity once i import them.

I believe i know the reason but i refuse to accept restarting my whole texture/material process.

Okay so i'm using cycles render, i make the materials for my model and assign their locations then it's all done.

I import and my materials are blank and not the RGB input materials that i made.

I just want my models simple colors and not image textures.
I believe im missing something simple and need some help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about blender compatibility with 3rd party software.